# Eclipse javafile color

Tags: eclipse

I dont know why but this is driving me insane, does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

first the whole thing is red, everyone of my java files (only in this one project) is like this. second, that dot next to the D, that is not the "edited without save" asterisk, it still shows up there after I edit something along side this dot. How do I remove both the dot and the red and go back to the white background? Thanks

Comment: Is there anything in `Error Log` view?

Comment: Nope as far as I can tell its not an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting of those entries are governed by label decorations. Possible you installed a new plug-in, that set up a new type of decoration that looks wild. You try to disable them to detect the source of the issue.

Generic Label decorations are set in **General/Appearance/Label Decorations** page in *Eclipse Preferences*, but the various Team providers (CVS, SVN, Git, etc.) also provide such options (**Team/xxx/Label Decorations**). Additionally, you could search for the string **Label Decorations** in Preferences using the search bar.

Comment: for future reference it was "Git Decorator"